# Producer Surplus

Tags: calculus, integration

If a supply curve is modeled by the equation

$$p = 600 + 0.1q ^{1.5}$$ find the producer surplus when the selling price is $\$700$.

I did this problem multiple ways and still can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

$700 = 600 + 0.1q ^ {3/2}$

$100 = 0.1q ^ {3/2}$

$1000 = q ^ {3/2}$

$q = 100$

$$\int_0^{100}( 600+0.1q^{3/2}-700)dq$$

$$\int_0^{100}(0.1q^{3/2}-100)dq= \frac2{25}(100)^{5/2} - 100(100) - (0-0)=9360$$

Comment: We can't tell what you are doing wrong if we don't see what you are doing.

Comment: could you elaborate on what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0):

This video may be helpful:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxuXVuXhaTU

Producer Surplus can be calculated as follows:

1) Find y-intercept (see chart)

```
  = 600 + 0.1(0)^1.5 ==> 600
```

2) calculate quantity demanded at $700 (i.e. solve for q)

```
  700 = 600 + 0.1(q)^1.5 ==> 100
```

3) calculate the area of the triangle (see chart)

```
  = (1/2) ($700 - $600) (100) ==> $5,000
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Area above the supply curve upto price point line gives you the producer surplus. In which case you need to subtract the area enclosed by the supply curve from the area under the price point line.

Since the price point line p=700 intersects the supply curve at (100,700) by way of substitution, you have total area under this line = 700*100

Supplycurve, by way of integration gives you 600q + 0.1*(q ^2.5)/1.5. Apply the limits q = 0 to 100 for getting the area under this graph- which gives you arounf 66666.67.

The producer surplus becomes 70000-66666.67 = 3333.33